# Can we call a method in the same class C#

Tags: c#

I have the below scenario. I need to call a method which is implemented in the same class. But it is throwing errors. How can we rewrite this?

```
public class A
{
    Random random = new Random(2);
    string Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string randomString = GenerateString(5);

    public string GenerateString(int size)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Will this scenario works?

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned *what* errors are being thrown.

Comment: You cannot call instance methods from an instance field initializer. Create a constructor and call the method there.

Comment: Please read those error messages, they usually tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 6):

You need to learn about [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/constructor).
Specifically, in your code you need a constructor initializing *randomString*. Also, **Alphabet** is never going to change during execution, so it is a great candidate to become **[const](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants)**.

```
public class A {
    const string Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public A()
    {
        random = new Random(2);
        randomString = GenerateStrig(5);
    }

    public string GenerateString(int size)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
        }

        return new string(chars);
    }

    string randomString;
    Random random;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access non-static method GenerateString in static context.
You can write your code just like this:

```
public class A
{
    static Random _random = new Random(2);
    const string Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string _randomString = GenerateString(5);

    public static string GenerateString(int size)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this compile? It would never occurred to me to initialize a member variable like this.

Comment: Yes, it does. Well, there are many ways to initialize member variables. Personally, I would use static variables only in specific cases. I only wanted to show a different way of implementing the solution.

Comment: Cool! For some reason, it looks really strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to turn `randomString` *field* into read-only *property*:

```
string randomString => GenerateString(5);
```

all you have to do is to add `>` after `=`; further refactoring:

```
public class A
{
    //TODO: Random(2) for debug only; Random() for real life
    readonly Random random = new Random(2);
    // Alphabet is a constant isn't it? 
    const string Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    // read-only property; initial value is GenerateString(5)
    //TODO: You may want to capitalize the property - RandomString
    string randomString => GenerateString(5);

    public string GenerateString(int size)
    {
        // Validation
        if (size < 0)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size), "size must be non-negative");

        // Linq is often compact and readable
        return string.Concat(Enumerable
          .Range(0, size)
          .Select(i => Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)]));
    }
}
```

**Edit**: As Progman noticed in comments *property* (and thus `GenerateString(5)`) will be executed *each time* when accessed, e.g.

```
  A a = new A();

  // call randomString 3 times
  string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(0, 3).Select(i => a.randomString));

  Console.Write(test);
```

will print out three *different* values

```
RE5Z3
BSG80
R10ID
```

Comment: Might be tricky as `object_A.randomString` will return a new random string every time it is accessed (I believe).

Comment: @Progman - that is what I would expect, given the property name

Comment: Would be better to capitalize the property so that it actually looks like a property.

Comment: @Progman: Thank you! You are quite right different values, so if this behaviour is unwanted one I'll drop my answer

Answer (score 2):

Change what you have to include a default constructor that you call that from.

```
public class A
{
    Random random;
    string Alphabet;
    string randomString;

    public A()
    {
        Alphabet = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        random = new Random(2);
        randomString = GenerateString(5);

    }

    public string GenerateString(int size)
    {
        char[] chars = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = Alphabet[random.Next(Alphabet.Length)];
        }
        return new string(chars);
    }
}
```

It's generally considered best practice to initialize all of your member variables inside the constructor rather than when you declare them, it helps with readability and maintainability.